# Incorrect output,shows Class.forName as output

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

The code shows me the output as "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
Is it because of the database or something? I am using JSP here and trying to verify details of users.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
        <%@page import="javax.sql.*" %>
        <%
        try{
        String username=request.getParameter("user");
        String password=request.getParameter("pwd");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/tyit1", "root", "sphinx1");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from login where username='"+username+"' and password='"+password+"'");

        if(rs.next())
                       {
            String user=rs.getString("username");
            String pass=rs.getString("password");

        }
               else{
               out.print("Invalid Credentials!");
               }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
                               {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should seriously consider moving your Java code out of the JSP page.

Comment: What @TimBiegeleisen said. More info: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a class I opted for and for now we have this chapter going on. So can you please point the error in this code for now?

Comment: what's the problem? Any error?

Comment: Yeah, when I enter the username and password it shows, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" as output

Comment: Replace `out.println(e.getMessage());` with `e.printStackTrace();` and then paste the entire error message you get on screen.

Comment: Nothing gets printed on the screen :(

Comment: Do you know what this program is supposed to do? I suspect that it is working well.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to check from the MySQL database the username and password. If correct just print Welcome or something but it prints com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` will write the exception stacktrace to the log, not to the screen (i.e. the web page).  Almost certainly the exception is a `ClassNotFoundException`, presumably because the MySQL JDBC driver JAR isn't on the build path/classpath/whatever-your-IDE-calls-it.

Comment: Add `out.println("Welcome");` immediately after `String pass=rs.getString("password");`. Post the output.